# Parsing unescaped double quotes with fgetcsv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm importing a CSV file into a MySQL database. To parse the CSV I'm using `fgetcsv()`. The CSV contains " characeters that have not been escaped and causes and `error array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`

The CSV data is in this format:

```
"GR109     "," ",0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0," ","GRANT     ","M          ","W",0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0," ",0,0,0.0," "," "," ",2.42,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0," "," "," "," "," "," ",0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0," "," "," "," ","SELF COL  ","16 P PR.  "," ","PLAIN     "," ","R/E1ROW   "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","R/E1ROW   ","BEADED    "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","GRANT     ","GRANT     "," "," ","  "," ",0.0,"  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","VAMP LNG - BLK. CARAVELLE P/S. QTR. LNG./ TNG.LINING - BLK. TORINO. (GREY ""TORINO"" FOR LIZARD.)","GR109 COMPLETE"
```

My code:

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',', $enclosure='"', $escapestring='"')
{
if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
    return FALSE;

$header = NULL;
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escapestring)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
        else
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
return $data;
```

}

I added `$escapestring='"'`, but that didn't help. Is the error from ""TORINO"" where the " character is not escaped? If so, is there a way to handle these fields?

Comment: It look as if "" (2 double quotes) are to be parsed as quotes. Meaning, you could just replace/filter out those and you should be good to go.

Comment: You don't need to pass in the `$escapestring` as the double quote is already escaped by using double double quote. You can see this by just doing a fgetcsv on the single line you posted and you will get the correct array.Can you post a minimal CSV that leads to the error including the header?

Comment: Could you provide more of csv file? Especially header. Duplicated entries in header (empty strings, numbers) could mess up things.

Comment: [link](http://www.filedropper.com/style2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I found it. Definitely second parameter in `fgetcsv`, which is the length of the line, messed up a little. Just change it to 0 (function could work quite slower), or double it. 
When it was 1000 it was cutting each row into two rows, one with length exactly 1000 chars (cutting was done even in the middle of the world) and second row being the rest of the line up to newline character. So $row variable at first was an array with 117 length, then about 13, again 117 and 13.

Just change this:

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escapestring)) !== FALSE)
```

to this:

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escapestring)) !== FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly fine for me. In the example below I removed the header handling, since your example data does not contain any header.

```
<?php

function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',', $enclosure='"', $escapestring='"')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escapestring)) !== FALSE) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}

$result = csv_to_array('test.csv');
foreach ($result as $key=>$element) {
    echo $key . ' => ' . print_r($element,true) . "\n";
}
```

If the file `test.csv` contains your given csv string, then the obvious output is (shortened):

```
0 => Array
(
    [0] => GR109     
    [1] =>  
    [2] => 0.0
    [3] => 0.0
    // .....
    [127] =>
    [128] => VAMP LNG - BLK. CARAVELLE P/S. QTR. LNG./ TNG.LINING - BLK. TORINO. (GREY "TORINO" FOR LIZARD.)
    [129] => GR109 COMPLETE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = preg_replace('/"((?=[^"]*)(?=(?=[^"]*)))"/', '$1', $subject);
```

---

The regex above will remove double-quotes inside double-quotes.
It will for work with:

1. > "some text "inside quotes" more text"
2. > ""inside quotes" more text"

---

---

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/Awxk2V)